Plaid QuickStart Tutorial Invalid Product Error on Mac
I am following the QuickStart tutorial for Plaid https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sGBvKDGgPjc&list=PLyKH4ZiEQ1bGJQXLNhrKQtQK8ADWTDJ0Y using non-docker. I continue to get this error output:
display_message: null,
documentation_url: 'https://plaid.com/docs/#create-link-token',
error_code: 'INVALID_PRODUCT',
error_message: 'provided products are not valid',
error_type: 'INVALID_INPUT',
request_id: 'wvNOtcz1mM1H3TF'
This specific error_message is not on the Plaid troubleshooting page at all. The 'INVALID_PRODUCT' error usually comes up when trying to access a product you dont have access to, but in this case I'm only trying to access auth and transaction. Here is my env file (without the comments and the actual keys). I have copy pasted my keys several times to make sure they are correct.
# Get your Plaid API keys from the dashboard: https://dashboard.plaid.com/team/keys
PLAID_CLIENT_ID=***************************
PLAID_SECRET=***************************


PLAID_ENV=sandbox
PLAID_PRODUCTS=auth,transactions #could add identity here


PLAID_COUNTRY_CODES=US,CA

PLAID_REDIRECT_URI= #this is not necessary

The .env file is under the node folder, and I have tried it outside that folder as well. The front end runs fine, but the local host site gives me a similar error message. I have also checked my Plaid logs, which show a 400 error but no additional info. Please let me know if you have any idea what is causing this

I deleted the quickstart folder and ran the project using docker which worked immediately. Then I paused the docker version, and went through the npm install/run commands like i did before and it just worked.
